# Getting the registartion form values into another html page using cookies,javascript,html?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to display the data values from one html page to another html page using cookies and JavaScript. When I am using the "Method=Get",Url shows the values of registration page in "details.html" in browser. But when I try "Method=POST" I am not able to display the values in "details.htm" by using cookies and JavaScript.

Can anyone to help me to display the values from register.htm to details.htm by using cookies and JavaScript.
The two HTML and along with JS:
Register.htm file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color:lightblue;}
h1 {color:blue;
   text-align:center;
   text-decoration:underline;}
.rightAlign {text-align:right;
             padding-right:5px;
             width:50%}
</style>
<script>
function clearData() {
document.forms[0].firstname.value="";
document.forms[0].lastname.value="";
document.forms[0].dob.value="";
document.forms[0].state.value="";
document.forms[0].email.value="";
document.forms[0].tel.value="";
document.forms[0].pwd.value="";
document.getElementById('male').checked=false;
document.getElementById('female').checked=false;
}

function submitData() {

document.cookie='cookie_firstname='+document.forms[0].firstname.value+'path=/'
document.cookie='cookie_lastname='+document.forms[0].lastname.value+'path=/'
document.cookie='cookie_dob='+document.forms[0].dob.value+'path=/'
document.cookie='cookie_state='+document.forms[0].state.value+'path=/'
document.cookie='cookie_email='+document.forms[0].email.value+'path=/'
document.cookie='cookie_tel='+document.forms[0].tel.value+'path=/'
document.cookie='cookie_sex='+document.forms[0].sex.value+'path=/'
document.cookie='cookie_pwd='+document.forms[0].pwd.value+'path=/'

document.forms[0].submit();
}



</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="regDetails.html" method="post" onsubmit="submitData()">

<table style="border:0px; width:100%">
<tr><td colspan = 2>
<h1>Online Registration</h1>
</td>
</tr>

<tr><td colspan = 2 class="rightAlign">
<p style="color:red; font-family:verdana; font-size:11px;"><b>Note:</b> All * marks fields are mandatory to fill.</p>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class"rightAlign"><b>First Name</b><label style="color:red;">*</label></td>
<td style="font-family:courier;"><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class"rightAlign"><b>Last Name</b><label style="color:red;"></label></td>
<td style="font-family:courier;"><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class"rightAlign"><b>Date Of Birth</b><label style="color:red;">*</label></td>
<td style="font-family:courier;"><input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class"rightAlign"><b>Sex</b><label style="color:red;">*</label></td>
<td style="font-family:courier;">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="male" required>Male 
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="female" required>Female</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class"rightAlign"><b>State</b><label style="color:red;">*</label></td>
<td style="font-family:courier;"><input list="state" id="state" name="state" required/></td>
<datalist id="state">
<option value="punjab">
<option value="delhi">
<option value="haryana">
<option value="odisha">
<option value="madhyapradesh">
<option value="chattisgarh">
<option value="karnataka">
<option value="tamilnadu">
<option value="goa">
<option value="rajasthan">
<option value="bihar">
<option value="andhrapradesh">
</datalist>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class"rightAlign"><b>Email Id</b><label style="color:red;">*</label></td>
<td style="font-family:courier;"><input type="email" id="email" name="email" required/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class"rightAlign"><b>Telephone</b><label style="color:red;"></label></td>
<td style="font-family:courier;"><input type="text" id="tel" name="tel"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class"rightAlign"><b>Password</b><label style="color:red;">*</label></td>
<td style="font-family:courier;"><input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" required/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="padding-top:10px">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
<td class"rightAlign" style="padding-top:10px">
<button type="button" onclick="clearData()">Clear</button>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>

details.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quiz.js">
</script>
</head>

<body onload="showDetails()">
<form>

<div id="detailsContainerDiv">
<p>You have registered successfully with the following details:-</p>

<div id="details" style="width:400px;">
<table style="width:400px;" border="1">
<tr><td>First Name</td><td id="firstname" class="bold"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td id="lastname" class="bold"></td></tr>
<tr><td>DOB</td><td id="dob" class="bold"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Sex</td><td id="sex" class="bold"></td></tr>
<tr><td>State</td><td id="state" class="bold"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email</td><td id="email" class="bold"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Telephone</td><td id="tel" class="bold"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td id="pwd" class="bold"></td></tr>
</table>

</div>
<br />
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="startQuiz()">Start Quiz</button>
</div>
</div>
<div id= "quizContainerDiv" style="display:none;">
<ol>

<li>
 <h3>What is the capital of Tamilnadu?</h3>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q1ans" id="q1ans-A" value="A"/>
 <label for="q1ans-A">A)Chennai</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q1ans" id="q1ans-B" value="B"/>
 <label for="q1ans-B">B)Bangalore</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q1ans" id="q1ans-C" value="C"/>
 <label for="q1ans-C">C)Delhi</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q1ans" id="q1ans-D" value="D"/>
 <label for="q1ans-D">D)None of the above</label>
</div>
</li>

<li>
 <h3>Who is the current Prime Minister of India?</h3>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q2ans" id="q2ans-A" value="A"/>
 <label for="q2ans-A">A)Rahul Gadhi</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q2ans" id="q2ans-B" value="B"/>
 <label for="q2ans-B">B)Narendra Modi</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q2ans" id="q2ans-C" value="C"/>
 <label for="q2ans-C">C)Manmohan Singh</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q2ans" id="q2ans-D" value="D"/>
 <label for="q2ans-D">D)None of the above</label>
</div>
</li>

<li>
 <h3>Who is the winner of 2015 Cricket WorldCup?</h3>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q3ans" id="q3ans-A" value="A"/>
 <label for="q3ans-A">A)India</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q3ans" id="q3ans-B" value="B"/>
 <label for="q3ans-B">B)Australia</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q3ans" id="q3ans-C" value="C"/>
 <label for="q3ans-C">C)Bangladesh</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q3ans" id="q3ans-D" value="D"/>
 <label for="q3ans-D">D)Pakistan</label>
</div>
</li>

<li>
 <h3>When is the Independence day of India?</h3>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q4ans" id="q4ans-A" value="A"/>
 <label for="q4ans-A">A)26th January</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q4ans" id="q4ans-B" value="B"/>
 <label for="q4ans-B">B)15th July</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q4ans" id="q4ans-C" value="C"/>
 <label for="q4ans-C">C)15th August</label>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="radio" name="q4ans" id="q4ans-D" value="D"/>
 <label for="q4ans-D">D)None of the above</label>
</div>
</li>

</ol>

<button type="button" onclick="submitQuiz()">Submit Quiz</button>
</div>

<div id="quizResultDiv" style"display:none;">
</div>

<div>
<label>Hi <span id="name" class="highlightAns"></span>, you have successfully completed the Quiz.</label>
<h3><span id="numOfCorrect"></span>/4 correct.</h3>
<label>your score is <span id="score" class="highlightAns"></span></label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript file:

```
function showDetails() {

 document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML = readCookie("cookie_firstname");
 document.getElementById("lastname").innerHTML = readCookie("cookie_lastname");
 document.getElementById("dob").innerHTML = readCookie("cookie_dob");
 document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = readCookie("cookie_state");
 document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = readCookie("cookie_email");
 document.getElementById("tel").innerHTML = readCookie("cookie_tel");
 document.getElementById("sex").innerHTML = readCookie("cookie_sex");
 document.getElementById("pwd").innerHTML = readCookie("cookie_pwd");

}

function readCookie(name) {

var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++)
{
var c = ca[i];
while (c.cahrAt(0)=='') 
c = c.substring(1,c.length);
if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
        var cookieData = c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        var actualData = cookieData.substring(0,cookieData.indexOf('path'));
        return actualData;
}
return null;
}

function startQuiz() {
 document.getElementById("detailsContainerDiv").style.display='none';
 document.getElementById("quizContainerDiv").style.display='block';
}


function submitQuiz() {
 document.getElementById("quizContainerDiv").style.display='none';
 document.getElementById("quizResultDiv").style.display='block';

var correctAnsCount = 0;

if (document.forms[0].q1ans.value == "A") {correctAnsCount++;}
if (document.forms[0].q2ans.value == "B") {correctAnsCount++;}
if (document.forms[0].q3ans.value == "B") {correctAnsCount++;}
if (document.forms[0].q4ans.value == "C") {correctAnsCount++;}

var score = correctAnsCount*10;

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = readCookie("cookie_firstname");
document.getElementById("numOfCorrect").innerHTML = correctAnsCount;
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

save value:

```
localstorage.setItem("name in which you want to save value",object/variable)
```

get value:

```
localstorage.getItem("name in which you want to save value");
```

Comment: But I am trying to get the cookies by 
document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML = readCookie("cookie_firstname");   where I declare in my details.html page.
 I did understand to keep the above text where